# Dead key behavior on Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, macos, ime, dead-keys

When a dead key is pressed in Windows nothing is displayed. But in macOS, when a dead key is pressed the corresponding terminator is displayed and highlighted, awaiting another key to be pressed.

Is there such an IME for Windows or Linux as in macOS?

Answer (score 0):

**On Linux Mint 21**

**Menu**
Input method

Language settings

**Terminal**
mintlocale-im

Choose (none, IME or XIM)

After set, it is necessary Logout and Login.

It's necessary to set None to Dead key works on wine or playonlinux.